# Margin between sibling elements not collapse

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set margin between sibling element. All sibling elements have the margin collapse behavior except the glyphicon icon. 
Here the code:

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="front">
    <li>Click here for a random article</li>
    <li class="search-box">dfg</li>
    <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon"></li>
    <li>Click icon to search</li>
</div>
```

The margin between `<li>` elements are 10px except the `<li class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon"></li>`, the margins are 20px;.
Can some one help me make those margins consistent?

Comment: add the proper code needed to load glyphicons, otherwise we can't see what you're talking about...

Comment: am sure it's an `display: inline-block;` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would resolve your issue;

```
 <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon"><span></li>
```

> glyphicon glyphicon-search icon

adds styles for displaying an icon and are more specific than your styles so it overrides your styling.